# Views and relationships for the race result listing

Tags: views

I am migrating a static runners page to Drupal, most of it are race results. I'm thinking to create content types for the race result and for the event (so I can reuse it for announcing events) and some taxonomies, see the image.

Now, I'd like in my view to list all race results that meet certain criteria, e.g. for the season 2014/2015 and 10k distance. The problem is that this data is referenced from the Distance and Saison taxonomies through the Event. Tried to add relationship with Event, but don't getting values for distance or saison.

Is there a way to do this? Or better idea to make Event taxonomy?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could post a screenshot of your View configuration?  Adding a relationship to the Event should, as you say, give you what you need.

Also: please clarify what you mean by "Tried to add relationship with Event, but don't getting values for distance or saison." -- are you saying that after you add the relationship you don't have the ability to add a filter on the "Distance" or "Saison" fields on the event, or is it that the filter is not behaving how you expect?

Comment: Thanks Aaron, looks as if I've figure it out, see the screen shot attached. Next I want to try to add is contextual filter to filter results based on parameters. Let's see how this goes :-)